# Formatear JS & HTML con prettier

Tags: javascript, html

No he logrado configurara que prettier formatee mi código html y js solamente, no se que mas ponerle en mi configuración

Así lo tengo configurado:

```
    "editor.defaultFormatter": null,
    "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
    },
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
    },
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    // "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "prettier.arrowParens": "avoid",
    "prettier.jsxBracketSameLine": true,
    "prettier.bracketSpacing": true,
    "prettier.embeddedLanguageFormatting": "auto",
    "prettier.htmlWhitespaceSensitivity": "css",
    "prettier.insertPragma": false,
    "prettier.jsxSingleQuote": true,
    "prettier.printWidth": 100,
    "prettier.proseWrap": "preserve",
    "prettier.quoteProps": "as-needed",
    "prettier.requirePragma": false,
    "prettier.semi": true,
    "prettier.singleQuote": false,
    "prettier.tabWidth": 2,
    "prettier.trailingComma": "es5",
    "prettier.useTabs": true,
    "prettier.vueIndentScriptAndStyle": false,
```

Lo puse asi ya que tengo otro formateador para php y ahora prettier solo me formatea el código html y no el js

Answer (score 0):

Puedes reinstalar Prettier y solo deshabilitar php agregando:

```
"prettier.disableLanguages": ["php"]
```